# how to get records count of this month?

Tags: mysql

how to get records count of this month?

I want to count user of this month ? "this month" should be calculate by mysql itself. how to write the sql?

[image]

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `a`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `a`;
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `date` datetime default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of a
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('1', 'jimy', '2014-02-11 09:24:42');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('7', 'khon', '2014-02-19 09:24:50');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('3', 'tina', '2014-01-11 09:25:03');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('4', 'kelvin', '2013-12-11 09:25:09');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('5', 'ricky', '2014-02-12 09:25:14');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MONTH(date) only returns the month number, it won't work with multiple years data.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) count
FROM a
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM a.date) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM NOW())
```

Or you could use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) count
FROM a
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(a.date,'%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
Select    count(*) 
FROM      a 
WHERE     MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW())
GROUP BY  MONTH(date)
```

Comment: if this month is 03 , i want to let mysql get 03 , but no static num in sql "03" , the sql can not change when this month changed